Are there specific main challenges in extending the inscribed-square theorem from smooth to continuous loops?
According to this video https://youtu.be/IQqtsm-bBRU?si=pSXEDQjTugHhhtI9 on Toeplitz' conjecture, if I've understood correctly, it is known that every smooth simple closed curve has an inscribed square (i.e. contains a set of four points that form the four corners of a square) but it is not known whether the same holds when smoothness is relaxed to just continuity.
Are there any specific main challenges for extending from the smooth case to the continuous case?
E.g.: My first thought was that, given a simple closed closed curve $\alpha$, one could take a sequence of smooth simple closed curves $\alpha_n$ that converges in Hausdorff distance to $\alpha$, and then take a subsequence $\alpha_{m_n}$ for which the inscribed squares converge - but then, I guess the problem here is that the inscribed squares of $\alpha_{m_n}$ could converge to either an inscribed square of $\alpha$ or a single point in $\alpha$, and we need the former rather than the latter. So, I'm wondering: can the question about the continuous case be equivalently reformulated as a question about the smooth case, where we want it to be possible to choose the square to have a size larger than some lower bound that is constant across all the smooth closed curves within each of a certain set of classes [e.g. constant across all the smooth simple closed curves contained in a given region that is smoothly equivalent to an annulus]?
